# Where is Object reflective information stored?

Tags: java

1. What use could someone have to override this (getClass()) method? What purpose could it solve practically.
2. The java documentation says this: `By convention, the returned object should be obtained by calling super.clone. If a class and all of its superclasses (except Object) obey this convention, it will be the case that x.clone().getClass() == x.getClass().` Why would this be true? What does this truth hold? Where is the information being stored that knows what type of object it is? How does this work?

Sorry this question I deleted and I shouldn't have. I meant to edit it. Won't happen again.

EDIT: I misread the documentation, it is final X-(, but I still would like to ask the second question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Where is Object reflective information stored?

In the class.

> What use could someone have to override this (getClass()) method? What
>   purpose could it solve practically.

No purpose whatsoever, because `getClass()` is final, so it cannot be overridden, so your question isn't about anything that can actually occur.

> Why would this be true?

Because `Object.getClass()` returns the class of the `Object` it is called on, and because `Object.clone()` returns an object of the same class that it was called on, and because a chain of `super.clone()` calls will terminate at `Object.clone()`.

Comment: I'm still a little confused about it. Why would it possibly not return the same class if the chaining wasn't involved?

Comment: @rubixibuc Consider what would happen if there was an implementation of `clone()` somewhere in the chain that returned `new Object()`. It would satisfy the semantics of `clone()` but break everything else in sight.

Comment: so it doesn't have to do with the information stored in the Object part of the hierarchy? It seems like ur saying even it you satisfy the semantics it still might not be guaranteed?

Comment: @rubixibuc There is no 'information stored in the Object part of the hierarchy' except maybe the hashCode, so I don't know what that question means, and I haven't said anything about guarantees, so I don't understand your 2nd question either.

Comment: I wanted to know how an object knows what class it is, and how cloning maintains this information when copying the object.

Comment: @rubixibuc Every object knows what class it is by virtue of having a `getClass()` method. `Object.clone()` is ultimately implemented in native code, it can do whatever it likes.

Answer (score 2):

The `getClass` method is `public final`.  It can not be overridden.

Using `clone` is definitely not a good practice.

I think what the java documentation is saying is don't change the implementation of clone.  If you override clone, use `super.clone` to keep the same implementation.

If you don't change the implementation, what is the point of overriding?
You could add logging.
You could loosen it from `protected` to `public`.
etc

If you don't change the implementation, then it will have the standard implementation which evidently guarantees that property.  On the other hand, if you change the implementation, all bets are off.

Comment: Very sry about that, I didn't realize, but I still would like to find out the second part